# ST_Distance from one location to others

Tags: postgis, sql, distance, select

I have a table that contains different city buildings and
want to calculate the distance of all the buildings of a type to another with a specific id using the ST_DISTANCE() function

Comment: Do any answer work? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Use a single SQL expression (not nested) referencing the table twice with different aliases:

```
SELECT loc.name AS Einrichtungsname, ST_Distance(loc.geom, pt.geom) AS Distanz
FROM gebaeude_salzburg loc, gebaeude_salzburg pt
WHERE pt.osm_id = '159867730'
  AND loc.type IN ('school', 'kindergarten')
  AND loc.osm_id <> pt.osm_id
  AND ST_DWithin(loc.geom, pt.geom, 1000.0)
ORDER BY ST_Distance(loc.geom, pt.geom);
```

This also limits the query to geometries that are within a distance of 1000 from each other. Note that distance units depend on the SRID.

Comment: The first answer is generally exclude matching the same geometry, if osm_id were changed to a school or kindergarten. The second question is irrelevant, since ST_DWithin is already used to find geometries within a distance of 1000 from each other.

Answer (score 0):

It's not beautiful and might not be the fastest approach, but this should be what you want:

```sql
SELECT
  gebaeude_salzburg.name AS Einrichtungsname,
  ST_Distance(
    geom, 
    (SELECT geom FROM gebaeude_salzburg WHERE gebaeude_salzburg.osm_id='159867730')
  ) AS Distanz
FROM gebaeude_salzburg
WHERE
  gebaeude_salzburg.type='school' OR gebaeude_salzburg.type='kindergarten'
;
```

It takes rows from `gebaeude_salzburg` that have the `school` or `kindergarten` type and for each calculates the distance to the single building provided by the subquery.

PS: Make sure you are calculating those distances in a suitable coordinate system, e. g. a UTM zone.